# Using 3rd party invoice service in magento

Tags: magento

I use a service that makes invoices. This service has also a web service so that systems can create invoices automatically.

Now, i want to intergrate the invoices service with my magento.

How can i hook the order action, so when it finishes, i'll use the web service and will create invoice for the order?

Thank you!